# Override if statement with variables

Tags: javascript, if-statement, overriding

The below code is an existing function within a theme:

```
function WShare( selector ) {
    var $this = $( selector ), $parent = $this.parent();
    var opt = {
        url: window.location,
        text: document.title,
    };
    if ( window.selectedText ) {
        opt.text = window.selectedText;
    }
    if ( $parent.attr( 'data-sharing-url' ) !== undefined ) {
        opt.url = $parent.attr( 'data-sharing-url' );
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to change/swap `opt.text` into `opt.url` and `opt.url` into `opt.text` within the if statements.

The reason behind this, is that in the continuing JS these two elements need to be swapped. What is the best way to **override** this?

Comment: If you want to modify the function, what keeps you from copying it and changing it?

Comment: @JonasWilms because 2 exact same functions are being loaded on the page with your suggestion. That doesn't work and I cannot modify the core files. I need an override.

Comment: You can't just override code somewhere programmatically. Clone the library or whatever it is, and do the modifications.

Answer (score -1):

Just save the variable values and then reassign the object property values? Probably the most intuitive easy-to-read way to do it

```js
    var opt = {
        url: 'test1',
        text: 'test2',
    };

    var x = 1;
    
    if (x === 1) {
      var url_var = opt.url;
      var text_var = opt.text;
      opt.url = text_var;
      opt.text = url_var;
    }

    console.log(opt);
```

Comment: Could you please explain the first `var opt = { url: 'test1', text: 'test2', };` and `var x = 1;`? (btw I haven't downvoted).

Comment: @Demian I was just using dummy values to recreate an object with 2 properties just like you have in your code snippet. The var x was used just so that I can create a simple conditional statement and show how you can reassign the values of the object easily inside of a conditional

Comment: I understand; is t possible you take the values of my question into the answer, so I could verify it.